# Computer for DS curriculum

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I actually need to decide on which computer I will be taking for a Data Sciences curriculum, including machine learning and further hands on Hadoop. Some computer vision applications are also planned.

I already have a Tesla K20 5GB, I think it's enough for beginning, they suggest me the following choices :

Choice 1 : Core i5-4570n 16GB RAM, 240GB SSD+3TB HDD

Choice 1 : Ryzen 5 2600, 16GB RAM, 480GB SSD+3TB HDD

What would you recommend me ? Some changes can be done over configurations if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add - I've found a second high quality monitor to be invaluable in improving productivity when working with datasets.

Answer (score 0):

This is all more than enough for a Data Science curriculum. I did my Data Science masters programme with an Intel i5 from the 4th generation, 8GB RAM and a GTX 970.

The only bottleneck was the RAM from time to time. Therefore, I would recommend at least 16GB of RAM.

Currently, a [compute capability](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) of 3.5 is enough for an Nvidia graphics card to run [tensorflow 2.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#tensorflow_20_beta). The higher the better, of course. 4 GB of VRAM should be enough to train most convolutional neural networks with a reasonable batch size.

Answer (score 0):

From this [comparison](https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i5-4570-vs-AMD-Ryzen-5-2600/2770vs3955), I would recommend the laptop with the Ryzen 5 2600. It has more cores and threads which will be helpful when you are parallel processing, specifically since you mentioned Hadoop.